# GKScore doesn't reporting scores

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios7, game-center

Does anybody know, why this code isn't sending score to GameCenter? Authentication to GC is ok. My leaderboard is 1.

```
    - (void) reportScore: (int64_t) score forLeaderboardID: (NSString*) identifier
{
    GKScore *scoreReporter = [[GKScore alloc] initWithLeaderboardIdentifier: identifier];
    scoreReporter.value = score;
    scoreReporter.context = 0;


    NSArray *scores = @[scoreReporter];


    [GKScore reportScores:scores withCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
        //Do something interesting here.
        NSLog(@"sent");
    }];
}
```

I want to touch button and send some value to Game Center.

```
- (IBAction)sendScoreButton:(id)sender {
    [self reportScore:77 forLeaderboardID:@"1"];
}
```

Comment: In the Game Center sandbox environment, scores reflect to the leaderboard only after a second account also posts a score to the same leader board. Try creating/using a second account and posting a score to the leader board "1"

Comment: Thanks, I found problem in Capabilities - Game Center. Step: Add the Game Center entitlement to your AppID. There I have message: Generation of the team provisioning profile for App ID xxxxxx is still pending. How long could it take?

Comment: It should be instant actually, but from what I remember you need to create a separate AppID to use In App Purchases, Game Center and other specific functionality.